# Как лучше всего шифровать или переделать данные на JS?

Tags: javascript

Каким образом можно создать простой шифр, есть идея насчет написания своего шифрования по цифрам, допустим у нас такое значение: `3123` так вот, как преобразовать это, что бы в итоге  мы получали что то вроде такого `faddggfa`. В данном примере мы получили это так как
`1 = dd`
`2= gg`
`3 = fa`
Как легче всего реализовать такой код?
Или какой посоветуете способ шифровать данные а потом их обратно расшифровывать?

Comment: Если вам для "поиграть" - сойдет и ваш способ. Для серьезного шифрования - серьезные алгоритмы типа AES.

Comment: Какова цель шифрования?

Answer (score 4):

Простые способы - шифр Цезаря, шифроблокнот(XOR), таблица шифрования.
Самостоятельно придумать хороший алгоритм без знания теории маловероятно. Почитайте работы по алгоритму Диффи-хеллмана, арифметика на кольце, эллиптические кривые.

Кратко:
Самая большая проблема простых шифров в том, что они оставляют неизменной частоту встречаемости буквы. По этому признаку довольно легко расшифровывается сообщение. 
Поэтому первым делом надо нормализовать алфавит.

**И главное:** хороший алгоритм остается защищенным за счет сложности вычисления исходных данных по результату без знания секретного ключа, а не из-за сокрытия самого алгоритма.

Comment: По поводу субъективных советов: используйте шифроблокнот. Он прост и довольно надежен. Для защиты от перехвата - HTTPS-TLS